# How to use filter when object to be compared is empty?

Tags: javascript

I am iterating through my data object, have another object ('compareTask') and use filter method to return that object inside data where id does NOT match with id in object to compare with.

I keep (obviously getting  "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" if its an empty object or doesnt have said ID. I cant really put an if/else and check if its an empty object, because thats exactly one of the cases where I want to return. Any help would be great! Thanks!

```
  var data = {
    names: [
      { name: "mike", taskID: 1 },
      { name: "nat", taskID: 2 }
    ],
    jobs: [
      { name: "aaa", taskID: 3 },
      { name: "bbb", taskID: 4 }
    ],
    cities: [
      { name: "london", taskID: 5 },
      { name: "new york", taskID: 6 }
    ]
  }

  var compareTask = {
    triggers: [
      { name: "Plumbing", taskID: 9 },
      { name: "FireDepartment", taskID: 4 }
    ]
  }

  data.names.filter((item, index) => {
      return item.taskID !== compareTask.names[index].taskID
  })
```

Comment: if i use some instead of filter, I get same error

Comment: You see this error because there's no `names` property in `compareTask`. If you meant `compareTask.triggers[index].taskID` then I would have a look at [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: okay so then I cannot use some because i want to return if in compareTask is not object with id which is the case if its empty, if its a different property or if it has same property but different taskID

Comment: Also no reason to expect the indexing between them to match

Comment: please add the wanted result. (maybe somthing the one with `jobs`).

Comment: In the case provided it should return everything from data as nothing matches

Comment: Showing the desired output would've been helpful. I am assuming in the above case you want to return: `[ { name: 'mike', taskID: 1 }, { name: 'nat', taskID: 2 } ]`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and get only the elements who have not the `taskID` of `compareTask`.

```js
var data = { names: [{ name: "mike", taskID: 1 }, { name: "nat", taskID: 2 }], jobs: [{ name: "aaa", taskID: 3 }, { name: "bbb", taskID: 4 }], cities: [ { name: "london", taskID: 5 }, { name: "new york", taskID: 6 }] },
    compareTask = { triggers: [ { name: "Plumbing", taskID: 9 }, { name: "FireDepartment", taskID: 4 } ] },
    result = data.jobs.filter(item =>
        compareTask.triggers.every(({ taskID }) => taskID !== item.taskID));
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works great!! Do you know what I could do if the compareTask object wouldnt be an array? var compareTask = {
         triggers: { name: "Plumbing", taskID: 9 }
      }

Comment: you could take the object directly without any iteration: result = data.jobs.filter(item => compareTask.taskID !== item.taskID);